# Widget following image

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I have a progress bar start out on each image and have it follow wherever the location of their respective image is? My main problem is that the self.squares dictionary and self.white_images dictionary are separated and I don't know how to combine them. self.squares has the buttons and positions but not the images while self.white_images have the images but not the buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, HORIZONTAL
import string
import os, sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage


class Board(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, length, width):  # self=Frame, parent=root

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.config(height=100 * self.length, width=100 * self.width)
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.pack()

        self.square_color = None
        self.squares = {}
        self.ranks = string.ascii_lowercase
        self.white_images = {}  # stores images of pieces
        self.white_pieces = ["pyimage1", "pyimage2", "pyimage3", "pyimage4", "pyimage5"]
        self.buttons_pressed = 0
        self.turns = 0
        self.sq1 = None  # first square clicked
        self.sq2 = None
        self.sq1_button = None  # button associated with the square clicked
        self.sq2_button = None
        self.piece_color = None
        self.set_squares()

    def select_piece(self, button):
        if self.buttons_pressed == 0:
            self.sq1 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
            self.sq1_button = button
            self.buttons_pressed += 1

        elif self.buttons_pressed == 1:  # stores square and button of second square selected
            self.sq2 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
            self.sq2_button = button
            if self.sq2 == self.sq1 or self.sq2[0] != self.sq1[0]:
                self.buttons_pressed = 0
                return
            if True:
                self.squares[self.sq2].config(image=self.sq1_button["image"])
                self.squares[self.sq1].config(image=self.white_images["blank.png"])  # clears sq1
                self.buttons_pressed = 0
                p = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=70)
                p.place(in_=button, x=5, y=5)

    def set_squares(self):  # fills frame with buttons representing squares

        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                for i, frame in enumerate((self.frame1, self.frame2)):
                    pos = self.ranks[x] + str(y + 1)
                    b = tk.Button(frame, bg=self.square_color, activebackground="lawn green")
                    b.grid(row=x, column=y, sticky="nsew")
                    b.config(command=lambda key=b: self.select_piece(key))
                    self.squares[i, pos] = b

    def import_pieces(self):  # opens and stores images of pieces and prepares the pieces for the game for both sides
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "white")  # stores white pieces images into dicts
        w_dirs = os.listdir(path)
        for file in w_dirs:
            img = Image.open(path + "/" + file)
            img = img.resize((80, 80), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.white_images.setdefault(file, img)

    def set_pieces(self):  # places pieces in starting positions
        dict_rank_pieces = {"a": "dirt.png", "b": "fire.png", "c": "metal.png", "d": "water.png", "e": "wood.png"}
        blank_piece = "blank.png"
        for rank in range(1, 6):  # fill rest with blank pieces
            for file in range(5):
                starting_piece = dict_rank_pieces[self.ranks[file]]
                pos = self.ranks[file] + str(rank)
                self.squares[0, pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece if rank == 1 else blank_piece])
                self.squares[1, pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece if rank == 5 else blank_piece])

        self.frame1.pack(side='left', padx=10)
        self.frame2.pack(side='right', padx=10)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")
board = Board(root, 5, 5)
board.import_pieces()
board.set_pieces()
board.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not understandable why you want to combine the two dictionaries because their usage are different.  If you do want to combine them, then what are the *keys* and *values* in the combined dictionary?

Comment: I’m not necessarily trying to combine them, that was just my approach. I just want a progress bar to start on each image and follow said image. My goal is to make a health bar.

Comment: What do you mean by *"follow said image"*?

Comment: I’m trying to make each image have a health bar.

Comment: You already know how to put a progressbar in a button when a button is clicked.

Comment: I’m not sure how to place a progress bar starting out on a button and I want something that checks if a button has a certain image on it and place a progress bar on that image.